# How do i underline half the length of a word or a number of words side by side? Thank you so much

Tags: underline

I want to underline with half the length of a word or a number of words side by side like picture below. Thank you for reading my question.

[image]

Comment: Can you add the purpose to the question? Is it for design or does it follow a technical purpose? Normally this is done with savebox. You store the content into an sbox, insert the sbox, measure it, use the measurement.

Comment: Maybe it would be sufficient to just underline from the h in định to the h in chỉ with `\uline` (from the `ulem` package) or similar (adjusted of course for your actual text)?

Comment: You could also overlap the text with an underline using \rlap, \llap, or \makebox[0pt], depending on how you want to specify the starting and stopping locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A centered title with an underline-like rule can be easily achieved within `center` and with a `\rule`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \bfseries
  LOREM IPSUM
  
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  
  \rule[\baselineskip]{.3\linewidth}{.4pt}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

In general, `\rule[<raise>]{<width>}{<thickness>}` sets a rule spanning `<width>` horizontally, `<thickness>` in height (the "line width of the rule") and raised by `<raise>` (negative an it'll lower the rule). Adjust the lengths to suit your needs.

Comment: But it add a vertical space after  last row because \rule[\baselineskip]{.3\linewidth}{.4pt}. How can i avoid it?

Comment: @tungsondkh: Check out [this options](https://pastebin.com/raw/rw8g39bU). You can either insert a negative `\vspace` just after the `center` environment (easiest), or set the title and the rule on the same line in zero-width boxes.